# how to replace null with 0 in scala array

Tags: arrays, scala

I am a scala beginner and I face a problem when I am doing my homework because there is null in the text file for example (AFG,Asia,Afghanistan,2020-02-24,1.0,1.0,,,,,0.026,0.026). So, **I need to replace the null in array with zero**. I read the scala array members and try the update and filter method but I cannot solve it. Can someone help me?

```
    val filename = "relevant.txt" //Access File
val rf = Source.fromFile(filename).getLines.toArray //Read File as Array


for(line <- rf){ //for loop
  line.(**How to replace the null with 0?**)

  //println(line.split(",")(0))
  if (line.split(",")(0).trim().equalsIgnoreCase(iso_code)){ //check for correct ISO CODE , ignores the casing of the input
    
  total_deaths += line.split(",")(4).trim().toDouble //increases based on the respective array position
 
  sum_of_new_deaths += line.split(",")(5).trim().toDouble
 
  record_count += 1 //increment for each entry

  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want `AFG,Asia,Afghanistan,2020-02-24,1.0,1.0,,,,,0.026,0.026` become `AFG,Asia,Afghanistan,2020-02-24,1.0,1.0,0,0,0,0,0.026,0.026` ?

Comment: yes, that's what I mean

Comment: `val cleanLine = ",\\s*(?=,)".r.replaceAllIn(line,",0")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val cells = line.split(",")
                .map(_.trim)
                .map(it => if (it.isEmpty) "0" else it)
```

Then you can use it like `total_deaths += cells(4).toDouble`

---

BTW, `null` usually refers to "null pointer" in scala.

In your case, you don't have any "null pointer", you just have "empty string"

Answer (score 0):

What you may do is something like this:

```scala
for (line <- rf) {
  val data = line.split(',').toList.map(str => Option(str).filter(_.nonEmpty))
}
```

That way `data` would be a `List[Option[String]]` where empty values will be `None`, then you may use pattern matching to extra the data you want.

Answer (score 0):

if you had to apply the change where you want:

```
//line.(**How to replace the null with 0?**)
```

you could do:

```
val line2 = if (line.trim().isEmpty) "," else line
```

then use line2 everywhere else.

As a side thing, if you want to do something more scala, replace .toArray with .toList and have a look at how `map`, `filter`, `sum` etc work.